# Disable UDP checksum in C (user-space)

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I want to disabble UDP checksum for my packets.

I'am using C and I know there is a flag `SO_NO_CHECK` but I believe it only applies to the kernel (?). Is there any way to do it from USER SPACE?

```c
int enable = 1;
if (setsockopt(client_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NO_CHECK, &enable, sizeof(enable)) < 0) {
    perror("Error setting SO_NO_CHECK option");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "disable UDP checksum"?  Do you mean checksums should not be computed for outgoing packets?  That that they should not be checked for incoming packets? Something else?  And how will you know?

Comment: But I think you are confused about socket options.  If your system supports `SO_NO_CHECK` then it should do so in userspace.  That will then affect the behavior of the kernel when processing UDP datagrams associated with your socket.  I do not find the option documented for Linux, but do refer to kernel developer [Andi Kleen's remarks on that topic](https://linux-man.vger.kernel.narkive.com/2tUG428v/so-no-check-socket-option).

Comment: Yes, exactly, I would like to have kernel not wasting time with processing checksum for outgoing packets. Actually, I would like to have the kernel doing as little as possible and just get my packets to the NIC!

Comment: Per Andi Kleen in the linked message thread: "On Linux UDP checksums are essentially free and there's no reason to turn them off and it would disable another safety line."  But if you insist on doing it anyway then `SO_NO_CHECK` should work.

Comment: The cost of computing the checksum in UDP is not high to be an issue, and getting a packet with a bad checksum is far worth considering not to take it off.